# Writing Arabic Numbers in a Right To Left TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `Form` localized to Arabic-Saudi Arabia (ar-SA), the form has `RightToLeft Property` set to `true`, `RightToLeft Layout` also set to `true`, now my problem is that the customers receive a number like this one:

773/17/26, but as you know, Arabic is written from right to left, so when the user reads this number or tries to enter it, he starts reading from the number **26**, not **773**, so what he really types on the keyboard is: 26/17/773, but the actual number is 773/17/26.

Now, I couldn't find a way to do that in .NET Windows forms textbox.

For reference, you can try doing that in Microsoft Word; In Word => Word Options => Advanced => Show Document Content => Set Numeral to Context.

When the keyboard input is set to Arabic language, you can write any number in Arabic and also in the required format, I mean the cursor always moves from right to left in Word.

Now, this is something I am not able to do in my form; I want the textbox's cursor to always keep moving from right to left not from left to right.

To sum up, the user will press the keys 26/17/773 respectively, but what I need to see in the textbox is 733/17/26

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have to admit I assumed that if typing that from right to left you would be typing things literally reversed rather than reverse by group. Does that mean that in Arabic numbers are the same way round as in english?

Comment: Yes they are the same , i might had a hard time explaining what i meant in English , but please apply that Microsoft example that i mentioned above , it will really help you understand what i really meant , thank you .

Answer (score 2):

By the way i got a help and this was the answer :

```
 private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == '/')
            {
                textBox3.SelectedText +=" ";
            }
        }
```

and it worked just like i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.KeyChar == '/')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            textBox3.Text = "/" + textBox3.Text;
        }
}
```